# Visual Studio Ultimate can't add table in design view

Tags: visual-studio

I am having trouble with creating tables in VS 2012 and cant seem to resolve this. I loaded Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate yesterday, didn't do any manual configuring just let it install. Couple of days later tried to add a table in my solution in Design view by right clicking the Tables icon in Server Explorer, and the error seen in the image below appeared, I thought it might be a problem with my solution so I created a another, and another, but still had the same problem.

Is this a known issue in VS 2012 Ultimate, or is there something I'm missing here? Is there a fix or a workaround?

[image: Error shown when trying to open table designer in VS 2012]

Answer (score 0):

go to programs and features of your windows as if you are going to uninstall VS and click repair.. it solved the problem to  me